# Query SUM devuelva 0 cuando los items esten en falso Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, querybuilder

Mi problema consiste en un query que estoy haciendo el cual me suma lo ítems que están activos por cada cliente: hasta allí todo bien. Mi problema viene cuando desactivo los ítems, deseo que me devuelva 0 por cada cliente y que ese 0 me lo devuelva únicamente cuando no haya ningún ítem activo de ese mismo cliente... Por acá dejo mi código

```
 $sum = facturacion::select('Importe', 'clients_id')
                ->selectRaw("SUM(Importe) as s")
                ->where('Status', true)
                ->groupBy('Importe', 'clients_id')
                ->orderBy('clients_id','Desc')
                ->get();

foreach ($sum as $key => $value) {
                $s = $value['s']. '<br>';    
                echo $s;
        }
```

Los datos que me trae esta consulta son los siguientes

`clients_id = 1, Importe = 49.9966`

`clients_id = 2, Importe = 236` <- Aquí hay 2 items los cuales ya están sumando su monto por separado, es de 118 cada uno de ellos...

`clients_id = 3, Importe = 118`

`clients_id = 4, Importe = 59`

En este caso si alguno de estos ítems = "IMPORTE"  está en false simplemente que salga un 0 cuando no haya ningún ítem = "IMPORTE" activo...

Cada uno de estos datos son ítems con un importe en específico los cuales tiene cada cliente por separado.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. La pregunta es: los clientes que no tienen items activos, salen en la consulta? Si salen, es sólo validar si `s` viene nulo o vacío; si no salen, tendrías que cambiar la consulta o traer el listado de clientes por aparte y buscar en uno y otro lado. No sabemos cómo están tus datos ni qué sale en la consulta, así que nos toca preguntar. POR FAVOR, RESPONDE EDITANDO LA PREGUNTA: ve a [edit] y aclara estos detalles.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, he intentarme ayudar en efecto cuando el cliente tiene sus items en falso me trae null... no muestra nada al respecto y deseo que cuando no haya nada mas que sumar... simplemente muestre 0 por cada cliente

Comment: Entonces, tienes un `$value['s']` que es NULL en ese caso? Y si validas antes de hacer echo si es NULL y pintas un cero?

Comment: lo que hace esto es traerme el importe la suma por cada cliente `$value['s']`, al hacer esto que me indicas cuando esta null... es ponerme tanto el true y false a la vez solo necesito que muestre 0 unicamente cuando no haya ningun item activo de ese mismo cliente

Comment: La forma más fácil de explicarnos lo que no entendemos los que queremos responder es **yendo a [edit] y poniendo un ejemplo de qué datos salen en esa consulta**, con eso no estamos adivinando

Comment: Hola ya intente explicarme de la mejor manera posible... no se si es entendible...

Answer (score 0):

actualización de mi problema ya he logrado solucionarlo de la siguiente manera en el mismo query hago la validación y muestro un 0 cuando ya no hayan ítems activos dejo mi código por acá por si alguien necesita hacer algo como esto, saludos...! @alfabravo gracias por intentarme ayudar también...

```
$sum = facturacion::select('Importe', 'clients_id')
            ->selectRaw("SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN Importe Else 0 END) as s")
            ->groupBy('Importe', 'clients_id')
            ->orderBy('clients_id','Asc')
            ->get();  

    $sumS = [];
    foreach ($sum as $key => $value) {
        $s =$value['s']; 
        array_push($sumS, $s); 
    }
```

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.